# Print data attribute of object tag

Tags: javascript, html, printing

I am currently trying to setup a system where I can call the browser's print function to print the data attribute of an object tag. I.e. I have a object tag with a pdf as the content, and  I want a way that when I press a button I can print just the pdf.

This is what I currently have.

```
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function printMe () {
      var test = document.getElementById('pdf');
      test.focus();
      test.print();
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <object data="test.pdf" type="application/pdf" id="pdf"></object>
  <button onclick="printMe()">Print!</button>
</body>
```

Now I keep getting an error, `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function` when I click my button. What am I doing wrong here and how do I set this up properly?

Comment: you can only print a document, not an element, using window.print().

Comment: Is there anyway to setup the pdf as a "document" that can be printed on it's own?

Comment: you MIGHT be abler to use an iframe or window.open instead, and then call the new frame/window's .print() method. might.